# Medical Certificates expiration

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

To contact athletes need to register medical certificates. I added a custom field multiple date expired. How do I retrieve all the contacts that do not have a date or that date has expired? How do I get a monthly list of certificates that expire?
Thank you.

Marco

Answer (score 4):

You can use the search builder to search any fields that are empty or null:

civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1 (should be in your Search menu item)

We also use a report for tracking a very similar thing. We use the Contact Report (Summary) Template (it might say Constituent instead of Contact)

As long as you've built the field to be searchable, it will be included in your report (this is a check box at the bottom of the field)

You can then select the fields your interested in seeing and filter the report to show those where the field "Expiry Date" = This Month

We trigger this report to be emailed on the first of the month so you can immediately see who requires renewing.

As you're using a relative date, it will always be current for the month you're in.

You can also build a smart group this way, and always have a current list of those who will expire this month which you can use in searches / mailings as you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the search builder i haven't my custom field, why?

Comment: it is a multiple record custom field

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot that you said it was a field that stored multiple values. We actually don't use that function because those fields aren't searchable and exportable in the same way as a standard field. Would you need a history of all the expiration dates over time? Perhaps you could create a custom activity that you could store that in and then use an activity report to find those scheduled for this month?

Comment: Yes history. Can i create an activity that take a value in multiple custom field and put the last in the custom not multiple field? And how if yes? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use the multiple field set function at all. You cannot search, report or export on those types of fields as you can with a standard CiviCRM field. I'd build a single field set to record the relevent data in a custom activity called something like "certificates expiration". You could use the activity date or build a new date field depending on your needs. You can then use the activity report to filter for activities of that type which are expiring that month. You could complete the activity to reflect it had been dealt with, and then create a new activity for the next renewal.